# How to remove cache from GWC for a specific layer

Tags: geoserver, curl, post

I am trying to remove the cache from a specific layer using curl 
so far i got to

```
curl -v -u user:password -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<truncateLayer><layerName>workspace:layername</layerName></truncateLayer>"  "http://hosttogeoserver/geoserver/gwc/rest/masstruncate"
```

I get : 
 `< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Date: Fri, 13 Nov 2015 15:37:16 GMT
< Server: Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.0..8
< Allow:
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`

Whereas if I do a simple GET request : `curl -v -u user:password-H "Accept: text/xml" http://host/geoserver/rest/workspaces/WORKSPACENAME/datastores/DB_NAME/featuretypes?list=available`

The response status 200 and outputs the correct information.

I've removed proxy/firewall, etc...

Any ideas?

Comment: What did you use as reference when you wrote your REST query? It does  not look similar to a seed-truncate example in http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/rest/seed.html.

Comment: Hi i based my query on http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/geowebcache/rest/masstruncate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end i hadn't enabled tomcat POST&DELETE request

For info in your tomcat dir your must modify **web.xml** 
And add :

```
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>

...

<init-param>
        <param-name>readonly</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

...

Answer (score 1):

If you use opengeosuite i think that the rest url for geowebcache is different than the url for geoserver, so you should hit this direction:

```
http://localhost:8080/geowebcache/rest/
```

instead of this

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/
```

Your complete curl request should look like:

```
curl -v -u user:password -XGET -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<truncateLayer><layerName>workspace:layername</layerName></truncateLayer>"  "http://hosttogeoserver/geowebcache/rest/masstruncate"
```

Comment: Using the Get method my curl works fine, i tried ur answer still getting a 405 Method not Allowed ='(

Comment: That's weird as the doc says that POST is a valid method. Which version are you using?

Comment: 2.4.4. it must do with a security issue...

Comment: It's and old version, i can't find the doc online. Try to check the off-line doc of the suite, usually on http://localhost:8080/opengeo-docs/geowebcache/